# How to setup laravel to use one app and point multiple domains to it

Tags: laravel, nginx

I have multiple domains, and would like to point them all to the same app.  I want them all to serve the same pages, but the way it's setup now, I get a 404 not found if I try to go anywhere in the app other than the home page.

I have the nginx server block setup with `server maindomain.com www.maindomain.com seconddomain.com www.seconddomain.com thirddomain.com www.thirddomain.com`

I also have SSL certificates setup for all the domains listed, and the test out with an A from SSL labs.  Question is, how do I get them all to serve the pages in the app, and not just the main domain's homepage?

I have looked at similar questions, but they don't seem to address this exact issue.  I don't want multiple domains pointing to different views (that's cool, but not what I need), and I already have a different app with a different name hosted on the same server and working correctly.  I've tried forwarding in the past, but it didn't work out (SSL issues).

Comment: Laravel handles domains really, really well, so you don't need to do anything in Laravel itself.

Comment: So do I just need to setup different server blocks for each domain name instead of listing each domain at the server line?  I don't understand why it doesn't work how I'd hoped.

Comment: sounds like pretty urls wasn't setup correctly, since the only thing that works is the homepage

Comment: I'm an extreme newbie to laravel.  Thanks.  I'll look into that.

Comment: If you mean by setting this up in nginx,  I do have it:
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}